# How to evaluate the sum $\sum_{k = 0}^{n}2^k {{n}\choose {k}}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

How do I evaluate the sum:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n}2^k {{n}\choose {k}}$$
I know that $2^k = {n \choose 0} + {n \choose 1} + {n \choose 2} + {n \choose 3}... {n \choose k}$, but I don't know how to proceed from this.

Comment: Hint: Look at the _binomial theorem_.

Comment: Why didn't you consider doing some actual numerical examples for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$? By that point a conjectural answer would become obvious. You should put more work into exploring with numerical data before giving up and saying you don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @KCd Numerical answers mean nothing to me. Because of the answers below, I now understand the *process* that people took to arrive at the summation, which is what I take out of this.

Comment: @Vishwa,Often,it so happens that we can't spot the solution at one glance.It then becomes necessary to investigate the problem using a tool that Paul Zeitz refers to as 'getting your hands dirty'.Since you couldn't directly spot the use of binomial theorem,numerical data would go a long way to help you conjecture a solution and then prove it.That is,what I believe,KCd was talking about.

Comment: @VishwaIyer: What rah4927 wrote is indeed what I meant. I did not write that numerical data alone would lead to a complete solution, but rather that it would tell you what to conjecture the formula should be. If someone told you a sequence $a_n$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ has initial values 1, 3, 9, 27, 81, wouldn't you guess $a_n = 3^n$? This is *exactly* what you'd find if you did some numerical examples with your sums. Since you wrote your question with no idea of what the formula *might* be, I was advising you that by at least trying out some examples you would have made a first key step.

Comment: @VishwaIyer: Saying "numerical answers mean nothing to me" does not reflect good work habits. When you're faced with a new expression whose value you want to understand, *if* it's accessible to numerical testing (which these sums are) then your first step should be to look at its values, since those values *may* suggest how to think about the problem once you know what you're looking for (in this case, explain why the values are powers of 3 after seeing they are powers of 3). If you develop the habit of trying examples as part of your work, you will be building an important skill for math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is known that:

$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}$$

For $x=2 \text{ and }y=1$: $3^n=\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k \binom{n}{k} $

Comment: Thank-you I didn't even notice you can use the binomial theorem

Comment: You are welcome!!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$
(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k
$$